# What are the hours for the airside Newark Liberty airport shuttle between Terminals A and C?

Tags: airport-transfer, ewr

There is a shuttle bus that runs between Terminals A and C at Newark Liberty. It looks like the shuttle closed down sometime after 11 PM. Does anyone know what time it reopens?

Comment: The airside shuttle or the regular airport shuttle?

Comment: Airside, after you've passed through security.

Answer (score 4):

While at the airport overnight I noticed there was a "closed" sign placed near the C71 shuttle door around 11 PM.  I made it over to Terminal A around 4:30 AM and noticed people arriving through the A28 shuttle door around 5 AM. So I believe the shuttle runs daily from 5 AM - 11 PM.